# Predict from Bayesian Network in R

Tags: r, predictive-models, bnlearn

I have a dataset whose variables are NUM type. I created two subsets train and test and a bayesian network using HC algorithm from test dataset. I want to predict a variable of the network based on the given train data set.

I used the following code:

```
library(bnlearn)
train = data.frame(df[1:120, ]) 
test = data.frame(df[121:130, ])
bn = hc(train) 
fitted = bn.fit(bn, data=train)   
pred = predict(fitted, node = "A", data=test, method = "bayes-lw")
cbind(pred, test[, "A"])
```

I got the following outpt:

```
       pred       Actual
 [1,] 0.1756733 0.07561605
 [2,] 0.1523257 0.04210418
 [3,] 0.1475759 0.08832813
 [4,] 0.1475458 0.06534838
 [5,] 0.1445587 0.06575709
 [6,] 0.1535988 0.08140954
 [7,] 0.1469534 0.11670950
 [8,] 0.1526856 0.12144097
 [9,] 0.1443011 0.13306547
[10,] 0.1427707 0.08459079
[11,] 0.1513976 0.10312063
```

The error of prediction is high. What steps should I follow to get a better prediction?

Comment: you could try estimating the coefficients using `penalized` and see if it offers any improvement (examples http://bnlearn.com/examples/custom-fitted/) but really prediction performance is dependent on the net. e.g. if you are trying to predict a leaf node with only one parent, you may not do a great job. Also `bnlearn` models the variables as linear which may not be reasonable.

Comment: ...   I know there are articles showing prediction by BN's  but structure learning really are better suited for understanding the dependency structure between variables (generative) which is often less suited to getting good  predictions.